# How do I tell the Canada Revenue Agency that they're sending someone else's documents to my address?

Tags: taxes, canada, debt, canada-revenue-agency

A business acquaintance used my address for mail correspondence, with my permission. Actually, he even didn't stay in my place and I don't have any of his personal belongings here. Later, I asked him to transfer his address to another place and I thought that he did.

Right now, he is abroad and sent me an email asking me to send him scans of letters if I get some with his name. I got a letter from Canada Revenue saying that he has tax debts, though not big amounts. They're promising legal action against him, like garnishing his bank account or seizing and selling his assets. I sent him scans of this letter, but I'm not sure if he will do something to resolve this problem.

I don't care about him; I just want to make sure Revenue doesn't bother me regarding him. How can I let thew know that he doesn't live here anymore? I don't think they will speak with me regarding his business. Maybe just put all his correspondence back in the Post Box and mark it "Wrong address"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Maybe just put all his correspondence back in the Post Box and mark it
>   "Wrong address"?

Precisely. Without opening. Just tell the postman that that person doesn't live there and have it returned to sender. The Revenue will figure it out. Most definitely do not accept any certified or registered mail not addressed to you personally.

Comment: yes, probably I don't have other choice. I sent him email, informing that I will do it for future letters.